# Spring + JPA LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean. packagesToScan regex support?

Tags: spring, jpa

I want configure my **EntityManagerFactoryBean** property "**packagesToScan**" to use a regex (like spring context **component-scan** does normally). But the most similar behavior that I can get is with an array of packages.

There are a version like this for use?

```
com.myproject.*.entity
```

this my **EntityManagerFactoryBean** config:

```
<beans:bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan">
            <beans:array>
                <beans:value>com.myproject.web.users.entity</beans:value>
            </beans:array>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="jpaProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop><!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do  -->
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
   </beans:bean>
```

Comment: No there isn't. But if everything is in the same base package just specify that `com.myproject` and it will scan all packages for `@Entity` beans.